# What does deriving mean when creating a datatype?

Tags: haskell

Suppose we look at:

```
data Quadrants = Origin |
                 Quadrant_I | Quadrant_II | Quadrant_III | Quadrant_IV |
                 X_Axis_Positive | X_Axis_Negative | Y_Axis_Positive | Y_Axis_Negative
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

What does "deriving (Show, Eq)" mean? I sometimes just see  "deriving (Show)".

Answer (score 7):

The `deriving` keyword "derives" implementations for certain type classes automatically. This works only with certain built-in type classes (including `Show` and `Eq`).

The `Show` instance that `deriving` creates produces the name of the constructor as a string and, if the constructor takes any arguments, the results of `show`ing each argument, separated by commas and surrounded by parentheses.

So for your type `deriving Show` would be equivalent to the following instance:

```
instance Show Quadrants where
    show Origin = "Origin"
    show Quadrant_I = "Quadrant_I"
    show Quadrant_II = "Quadrant_II"
    ...
```

Similarly the derived `Eq` instance considers two values equal if they were created using the same constructor and the same arguments. So for your type that'd be:

```
instance Eq Quadrants where
    Origin == Origin = True
    Quadrant_I == Quadrant_I = True
    Quadrant_II == Quadrant_II = True
    ...
    _ == _ = False
```

As you can see, using `deriving` can save quite a bit of code.

Comment: GHC also has some extensions for deriving other class instances aside from the handful of standard classes, since much of the time the code you need to write is as tedious and straightforward as shown here. (Commenting because I don't think this merits posting as a separate answer or cluttering this answer with an edit.)

Comment: Also note that deriving `Show` requires all the parameter types to be `Show`, and deriving `Eq` requires all the parameter types to be `Eq`, otherwise the default implementations can't work.